# How to pass a input text content to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the Unsplash API in order to input some keywords and then retrieve photos related to those keywords. In order to do that, I'm using the following Javascript:

```js
var APIKey = '{mykey}';

        $.getJSON('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=' + search + '&per_page=19&client_id=' + APIKey, function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            var imageList = data.results;

            $.each(imageList, function (i, val) {

                var image = val;
                var imageURL = val.urls.regular;
                var imageWidth = val.width;
                var imageHeight = val.height;

                if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
                    $('#output').append('<div class="image"><img src="' + imageURL + '"></div>');
                }

            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center">
        <form class="form-inline" method="post">
            <div class="form-group mx-auto my-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Procurar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="output"></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is use this input text and this button in order to change the value of the variable search which is on the URL.

I'm new with javascript but I think that what I'm missing is some jQuery syntax.

Comment: You need to put the `$.getJSON(...)` part inside a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) so you can run it after a button click. Note that functions are a fundamental building block of JavaScript and programming in general.

Comment: @ChrisG I usually understand what I need to do in a function, but in this case, I don't understand how to pass the value.

Comment: @lordewick jQuery is only available after the document is ready, read doc to understand how to use jQuery properly: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: If you actually use a function, you can pass the value as parameter: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jq6tsf31/

Comment: Thank you very much all of you for the help! It's working very well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1) Prevent page reload/submitting the form when clicking the button. You can remove the form element as you don't need to refresh the page but get the input text input or keep the form and change the input type from submit to a button one.

2) Hook on the button click event and then execute your GET request to unsplash api.

3) Put this event handler in a document ready event handler so it can trigger when you click the button.

4) Do your magic :)

I hope it helps. Try the snippet below with your API key.

```js
var APIKey = "{mykey}";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchBtn").on("click", function() {
    var searchQuery = $("#search").val();
    getJson(searchQuery);
  });
});

function getJson(search) {
  $.getJSON(
    "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=" +
      search +
      "&per_page=19&client_id=" +
      APIKey,
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      var imageList = data.results;

      $.each(imageList, function(i, val) {
        var image = val;
        var imageURL = val.urls.regular;
        var imageWidth = val.width;
        var imageHeight = val.height;

        if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
          $("#output").append(
            '<div class="image"><img src="' + imageURL + '"></div>'
          );
        }
      });
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center">
        <form class="form-inline" method="post">
            <div class="form-group mx-auto my-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
                <button id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Procurar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Goran. I've combined your answer with the help of the comments above and managed to do it. Thank you very much! You are all heroes for me today.

Comment: @lordewick glad that we were able to help :)